# how to calculate Euclidean distance for normalized data set

Tags: euclidean-distance

I have a numeric dataset contains age, length, weight,  the features are from different domains.I have normalized the data to get values for all the features between 0 and 1.

**Is it possible to apply normalized Euclidean distance on a normalized data set**
because when I applied **Euclidean distance** I have got distance values > 1. 
I want to get distance value between 0 and 1 **ONLY**  because I am going to calculate the similarity based on

```
S(x,y)= 1- d(x,y)
```

Comment: the euclidean distance between `(0,0,0)` and `(1,1,1)` is `sqrt(3) > 1`

Comment: I know that, but if we applied normalized Euclidean distance will be 1

Comment: define normalized euclidean.

Comment: can you see [this link](http://www.pbarrett.net/techpapers/euclid.pdf) pages 7,8

Comment: your distances are bounded by `d((0,0,0), (1,1,1)) = 1` for `d` being the normalized euclidean. So yes it should be possible.